# How to know when a particular ad is being served by Google Double Click

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

There are ads (line items) in my company's double click for publishers account. Some are ads to external sites and some are in-house ads, like an image that says we also have an android and iOS app available.

We show a link that says 'advertising' next to any ad. Clicking on that leads to advertising options on our website.

Now, we don't want to show this link how in-house ads. How can I know from the client site (through javascript) that the ad being served is in-house or not? I tried setting key-value pair on a line item and tried getting it via GoogleTag's `getTargeting(KEY_NAME)` function, but that doesn't seem to work. Not even sure if key-value pair can be used for such functionality.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think that's possible.

You could add some javascript to the creative to inform the site to remove the "advertising"-word?